# java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException while opening Excel file into JMeter

Tags: java, jmeter

I'm currently following this tutorial to read an Excel file into JMeter : https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-implement-data-driven-testing-in-your-jmeter-test

However, when I try to execute below part I'm facing an issue

```
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import java.io.*;

XSSFWorkbook book = "";
try {
    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("${PATH}"));
    book = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
    inputStream.close();
} 
catch (Exception e) {
     log.info("!!!!!!!!" + e.getMessage() + "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
}
```

Error is `!!!!!!!!java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!`

I imported below librairies into JMeter :

- Apache POI 3.17
- Apache POI-OOXML 3.17
- Apache Commons IO 2.6
- OOXML Schemas 1.3
- xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar
- commons-collections4-4.1.jar

and JMeter version is `5.1`.

Did you already faced this issue?

Many thanks in advance

Best regards

**UPDATE 1**

```
Target exception: org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 in inline evaluation of: ``import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook; import org.apache.poi.xssf.us . . . '' at line number 10
javax.script.ScriptException: Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook; import org.apache.poi.xssf.us . . . '' : Object constructor : at Line: 10 : in file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook; import org.apache.poi.xssf.us . . . '' : new XSSFWorkbook ( inputStream ) 

Target exception: org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 in inline evaluation of: ``import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook; import org.apache.poi.xssf.us . . . '' at line number 10
    at bsh.engine.BshScriptEngine.evalSource(BshScriptEngine.java:86) ~[bsh-2.0b5.jar:2.0b5 2005-06-12 04:50:41]
    at bsh.engine.BshScriptEngine.eval(BshScriptEngine.java:46) ~[bsh-2.0b5.jar:2.0b5 2005-06-12 04:50:41]
    at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_31]
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.processFileOrScript(JSR223TestElement.java:225) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1 r1853635]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JSR223Sampler.sample(JSR223Sampler.java:71) [ApacheJMeter_java.jar:5.1 r1853635]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:622) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1 r1853635]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:546) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1 r1853635]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:486) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1 r1853635]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:253) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1 r1853635]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_31]
```

Comment: Caused by what?

Comment: I don't have more information, that's why I'm not able to identify the issue. I think it happens during the object creation `new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream)`

Comment: Yes you do. It's in the stack trace.

Comment: I attached more info into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Man, we cannot help you with this by looking only at exception message, we need the [stacktrace](https://www.sentinelone.com/blog/java-stack-trace-understanding/).

The contents of [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) will be extremely helpful as well.

So far I can only recommend starting clean

1. [According to JMeter Best Practices you should always be using the latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) so visit [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page and fetch the latest stable version
2. Instead of individual .jar files you can download [tika-app.jar](https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/tika/2.1.0/tika-app-2.1.0.jar) and put it into [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)
3. Restart JMeter to pick the .jar up
4. Add the relevant [JSR223 Test Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and make sure to use [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) as the language
5. Change your `"${PATH}"` to `vars.get("PATH")`
6. Make sure to add all the necessary imports like `import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I added information in the question. However, I can't use the latest version of JMeter and I can't download `tika-app.jar`. Regarding the language, as mentioned in the tutorial I use `java`. Yes I have imported this library.

Comment: If you're ignoring my recommendations what else do you want from me?

Comment: Of course not. I found a solution to download the package `tika-app.jar` and it is working now. Thank you very much.